# Coq `ring` tactic with booleans: not a valid ring equation

Tags: coq

The [Coq docs](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/addendum/ring.html#theringandfieldtacticfamilies) say that the ring of booleans is predefined, and that all one has to do is `Require Ring.`

The docs also say that the `ring` tactic works by normalizing w.r.t. associativity and commutativity.

However, the `ring` tactic fails for this trivial proof that relies only on commutativity of `||` (`orb`):

```
Lemma ors: forall (a b: bool), a || b = b || a.
Proof.
intros.
ring.
```

```
Error: Tactic failure: not a valid ring equation.
```

What went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because Coq's standard library defines a [Boolean ring structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_ring) for `andb` and `xorb` operations. But to prove your lemma with the `ring` tactic you need a Boolean semiring. Here is how you can define it using [`Add Ring`](https://coq.github.io/doc/v8.11/refman/addendum/ring.html#coq:cmd.add-ring) vernacular:

```
From Coq Require Import Ring.
Open Scope bool_scope.

Lemma boolSRth : semi_ring_theory false true orb andb (@eq bool).
Proof.
constructor.
exact Bool.orb_false_l.
exact Bool.orb_comm.
exact Bool.orb_assoc.
exact Bool.andb_true_l.
exact Bool.andb_false_l.
exact Bool.andb_comm.
exact Bool.andb_assoc.
exact Bool.andb_orb_distrib_l.
Qed.

Add Ring boolsr : boolSRth (decidable bool_eq_ok, constants [bool_cst]).

Lemma ors a b : a || b = b || a.
Proof. ring. Qed.
```

Unfortunately, now this breaks using `ring` for goals involving `xorb` function.